# HTTPRequest roblox

Tags: http, lua, roblox

i'm currently making a roblox whitelist system and it's almost finished but i need 1 thing more i scripted it and its not work (code below) i didn't found nothing to fix what i have (script and screenshoot of error below), thanks.

```
local key = 1
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")


local r = HttpService:RequestAsync({
    Url = "https://MyWebsiteUrl.com/check.php?key="..key,
    Method = "GET"
})
local i = HttpService:JSONDecode(r.Body)
for n, v in pairs(i) do
    print(tostring(n)..", "..tostring(v))
end
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: let me send you a screenshoot link of the screenshot is : https://ibb.co/fXw0vGy

Comment: the error is `Can't Parse JSON`. Whatever you are getting back in `r.Body` it isn't JSON. you should try printing it out and seeing what it is. Or putting a breakpoint and inspecting the value. Are you sure you got a successful response from your website?

Comment: Yes i get the reponse whitelisted or notwhitelisted

Comment: That means the r.Body is an invalid JSON. You should send a correctly formatted JSON response from the API website.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the website that you are using to validate the key
returns the response in raw if so then

```
local key = 1
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
local r = HTTPService:GetAsync("https://MyWebsiteUrl.com/check.php?key="..key)

local response = JSON:Decode(r)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you tried to concat a string (the url) with a number (the key variable) try to make the key a string